# How can I filter parent entity where children entity contains value of another entity selected entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, filter

I have a parent entity with one to many children entity. First get a list of parent - child data from EF core. Then I try to run a Linq query against this list so I don't need to call SQL server on every filter change. This is done in C# and Blazor server.

```
Childentity :
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }  // the user could enter this text free, like a tag
public int ParentId { get; set; }
...

FilterEntity : (not in database, this is generated from childentity )
public string Text { get; set; }
public bool Selected { get; set; }
...
```

I'm trying to make a single line Linq query where I get a list of parent entity that has a children entity property "Text" that match any of Filterentity "Text" where Selected is true.
I don't know where to start. Maybe this isn't doable in a single line query?

I tried several similiar to

```
Parent.Where(i => i.Child.All(w => w.Text.Contains(z => FilterEntity
  .Where(w => w.Selected == true)))).ToList()
```

without any luck.

[EDIT]
Firo's solution with works but not all the way.

```
Parent.Where(i => i.Childen.All/.Any(w => Filters.Where(f => f.IsSelected).Select(f => f.Text).Contains(w.Text))).ToList()
```

Lets say I have

```
Parent1 with childs 
{ Id = 1, Text = "C#", ParentId = 1 }
{ Id = 2, Text = "Pascal", ParentId = 1 }
{ Id = 3, Text = "Cobol", ParentId = 1 }

Parent2 with childs
{ Id = 4, Text = "C#", ParentId = 2 }
{ Id = 5, Text = "Pascal", ParentId = 2 }

Parent3 with child
{ Id = 6, Text = "C#", ParentId = 3 }
```

And my filterentity "C#" IsSelected I got :

```
.All :
Only parent3
.Any :
All 3 parents
```

Here I will have what .Any result in, all 3 parents.

But with Filterentity "C#" and "Pascal" IsSelected I got :

```
.All :
Only parent2
.Any :
All 3 parent
```

Here I want to get parent1 and parent2.

Comment: It would help if you could post some sample data, so we can see what the input looks like and what results you expect. Also "_without any luck_" doesn't tell us anything. What did you get, as opposed to what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

one line

```
var result = Parents
    .Where(i => Filters.All(f => !f.IsSelected || i.Children.Select(c => c.Text).Contains(f.Text)))
    .ToList();
```

more efficient 2 lines

```
var activeFilters = Filters.Where(f => f.IsSelected).Select(f => f.Text).ToList();
var result2 = Parents
    .Where(i => activeFilters.All(f => i.Children.Select(c => c.Text).Contains(f)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to use something between .Any and .All.  Lets say I have 1 value that .IsSelected, on .Any I get all parent that has a child that has this value. But if I use .All, lets say my parent has 2 childs with values "C#" and "Pascal" and my filter has "Pascal", I only got parents that have only "Pascal"

Comment: @TobiasGustafsson can you formulate a rule when a parent satisfies the filters or give an example?

Comment: Have updated my question above, under [Edit]